How to add ThreeTenABP to decompiled APK with apktool?
The application I need, although compiled for API 23, uses Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter, available in API 26. I found a ThreeTenABP backport, but I don’t know how to add this library when I recompiling APK via apktool

The threetenabp library is provided as .aar file which is designed to be included when building an Android app. The classes are contained as Java byte code. If you want to include it via apktool you first need to convert it to DEX byte code and then to smlai files. But n the end this is all not necessary if you already have the DEX byte code.
Then you can add it directly to the APK you want to modify, without having to use apktool:

Download the latest threetenabp .aar file.

Open it with a ZIP tool and extract classes.jar

Convert it to dex, using e.g dx from Android SDK package "build-tools" v30.0.3:
Android-SDK\build-tools\30.0.3\dx --dex  --output classes.dex classes.jar

Now open the APK file of the app you want to modify. You don't need to use apktoolto decompile it. Simply open it in a ZIP tool like 7-Zip.

Check the APK root folder for the existing .dex files. They should be named

classes.dex
classes2.dex
classes3.dex
classes4.dex
...


If your APK file contains classes.dex files up up number 3 classes3.dex then rename the classes.dex file built in step 3 to classes4.dex

Include the renamed file from step 6 into the APK file

Perform ZIP-align and APK signing using apksigner


